How to fill in correctly App Store privacy policy when using AWS services?
I’ve developed some sort of ‘Tinder’ clone application, that’s using geo location and user profile data to match between users.
When deploying it to App Store, I’m faced with un-clear, legal jargon and terms in the privacy section.

If I’m using AWS as my third-party provider for hashing and storing user personal data (via cognito) and geo-location, how should I go about it and what should I fill it in?
Under Name: I’m asked “Are the names collected from this app linked to user identity?” - what do they mean by that and how should I address it if using the services as described?

Thank you!
